# Hot to serialize my payload to the PredictionServiceClient class?

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

I got a trained and deployed model based on an AutoML Table in GCP.

It answers to the request below in PowerShell:

```powershell
$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[MY-SERVICE-ACCOUNT-KEY-FILE].json"    
$cred = gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
$headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer $cred" }

Invoke-WebRequest `
-Method POST `
-Headers $headers `
-ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" `
-InFile [MY-REQUEST-FILE].json `
-Uri "https://eu-automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/[MY-PROJECT-ID]/locations/eu/models/[MY-MODEL-ID]:predict" | Select-Object -Expand Content
```

Corresponding response:

```json
{
  "payload": [
    {
      "tables": {
        "score": 0.9930415,
        "value": "Low"
      }
    },
    {
      "tables": {
        "score": 0.006626979,
        "value": "Medium"
      }
    },
    {
      "tables": {
        "score": 0.0003314384,
        "value": "High"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

All good. Now I want to make that call from C# using the Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1 .NET library following the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1.PredictionServiceClient#Google_Cloud_AutoML_V1_PredictionServiceClient_Predict_Google_Cloud_AutoML_V1_ModelName_Google_Cloud_AutoML_V1_ExamplePayload_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_String__Google_Api_Gax_Grpc_CallSettings_).

`<PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1" Version="2.3.0" />`

```
    // Create client
    PredictionServiceClient predictionServiceClient = PredictionServiceClient.Create();
    // Initialize request argument(s)
    ModelName name = ModelName.FromProjectLocationModel([MY-PROJECT-ID], "eu", [MY-MODEL-ID]);
    ExamplePayload payload = new ExamplePayload();
    IDictionary<string, string> @params = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "feature_importance", "true" }, };
    // Make the request
    PredictResponse response = predictionServiceClient.Predict(name, payload, @params);
```

Terminal:

```
Unhandled Exception: Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="InvalidArgument", Detail="List of found errors: 1.Field: name; Message: The provided location ID doesn't match the endpoint. For automl.googleapis.com, the valid location ID is `us-central1`. For eu-automl.googleapis.com, the valid location ID is `eu`.      2.Field: payload.payload; Message: Required field not set.        ", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1632383996.440000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:216.58.211.10:443","file":"..\..\..\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc","file_line":1067,"grpc_message":"List of found errors:\t1.Field: name; Message: The provided location ID doesn't match the endpoint. For automl.googleapis.com, the valid location ID is `us-central1`. For eu-automl.googleapis.com, the valid location ID is `eu`.\t2.Field: payload.payload; Message: Required field not set.\t","grpc_status":3}")
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg) in /var/local/git/grpc/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/Internal/AsyncCall.cs:line 78
   at Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request) in /var/local/git/grpc/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/DefaultCallInvoker.cs:line 46
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.<BlockingUnaryCall>b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx) in /var/local/git/grpc/src/csharp/Grpc.Core.Api/Interceptors/InterceptingCallInvoker.cs:line 51
   at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation) in /var/local/git/grpc/src/csharp/Grpc.Core.Api/ClientBase.cs:line 174
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request) in /var/local/git/grpc/src/csharp/Grpc.Core.Api/Interceptors/InterceptingCallInvoker.cs:line 48
   at Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1.PredictionService.PredictionServiceClient.Predict(PredictRequest request, CallOptions options) in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1/Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1/PredictionServiceGrpc.g.cs:line 281
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall.GrpcCallAdapter`2.CallSync(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings) in /_/Google.Api.Gax.Grpc/ApiCall.cs:line 92
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<WithRetry>b__0(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings) in /_/Google.Api.Gax.Grpc/ApiCallRetryExtensions.cs:line 78
   at Predict.Program.predict1(String project, String location, String model) in
```

Any idea on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message using a Java implementation. But when overriding the default endpoint as shown below, it works.

```
PredictionServiceSettings settings =
            PredictionServiceSettings.newBuilder()
                .setEndpoint("eu-automl.googleapis.com:443")
                .build();

try (PredictionServiceClient client = PredictionServiceClient.create(settings)) { ...
```

Unfortunately the .NET library doesn't provide a Create method taking settings as a parameter.

Comment: To specify custom credentials or other settings, use PredictionServiceClientBuilder.

Comment: That didn't give much from reading the documentation https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1.PredictionServiceClientBuilder

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation states that currently for .NET (C#) client library [the only supported `location_id` for autoML endpoints is `us-central1`](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.AutoML.V1.AutoMlClient#remarks), whereas you are trying to use an `eu` endpoint.

I have opened a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/205710028) to ask if other locations will be enabled in the future.

Regarding the second error, I think that it is due to the first one as you have exactly followed the official documentation’s example code, without providing any additional argument to the payload constructor.